# can monodb do this with $in,multiple input and fixed conditions,output like grouped result

Tags: mongodb

there is a colleciont named `group_members`:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd7"), 
    "uid" : NumberInt(1), 
    "group_id" : "g1"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd8"), 
    "uid" : NumberInt(1), 
    "group_id" : "g2"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd9"), 
    "uid" : NumberInt(2), 
    "group_id" : "g2"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd1"), 
    "uid" : NumberInt(2), 
    "group_id" : "g3"
}
```

I want the result like this `in a single query`,the key of map is input uid:

```
{1:["g1","g2"], 2:["g2","g3"]}
```

The input is uid array,like this: `[1,2]`,the condition is fixed of `group_id` array, like this:`["g1","g2","g3"]`

=================================

Can single query do this?

Comment: The result I want is uid 1 is in group_id array:["g1","g2"], uid 2 is in group_id array:["g2","g3"],etc, like `$unwind` input [1,2] and each item of input use `$in` the group_id array:`["g1","g2","g3"]`,then group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.test.aggregate(  
    [   
        {   $match: {"uid":{$in:[1,2]}, "group_id"：{$in: ["g1","g2","g3"]}}},
        {   $group   : { _id : "$uid",  group_id : {$push: '$group_id' }}},    
    ]  
)
```